# ASP.NET Core - Error CS1929 IMemoryCache does not contain a definition for 'GetString' and the best extension method overload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

I am implementing Redis for In-Memory caching in ASP.NET Core-6 using :

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis
```

I have this code:

```
public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public CacheService(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        var value = _cache.GetString(key);

        if (value != null)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }

        return default;
    }

    public T Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        _cache.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(20),
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I got these errors:

```
Error   CS1929  'IMemoryCache' does not contain a definition for 'GetString' and the best extension method overload 'EncodingExtensions.GetString(Encoding, in ReadOnlySequence<byte>)' requires a receiver of type 'System.Text.Encoding'
```

and

```
Error   CS1061  'IMemoryCache' does not contain a definition for 'SetString' and no accessible extension method 'SetString' accepting a first argument of type 'IMemoryCache' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Then:

_memoryCache.GetString(key) and _memoryCache.SetString are highlighted.

How do I correct these?

Comment: _"I am implementing Redis for In-Memory caching "_ - that's a bit strange statement, from .NET process point of view Redis is pretty much out-of-memory cache (i.e. out of process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not `GetString` method for [`IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), but [there is one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.distributedcacheextensions.getstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-caching-distributed-distributedcacheextensions-getstring(microsoft-extensions-caching-distributed-idistributedcache-system-string)) for [`IDistributedCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). If you want for development/testing purposes you can register `IDistributedCache` using the framework provided [Distributed Memory Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0#distributed-memory-cache) implemntation:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

But note that:

> The Distributed Memory Cache isn't an actual distributed cache. Cached items are stored by the app instance on the server where the app is running.

Also note that the `RedisCache` does not implement `IMemoryCache`, it [implements `IDistributedCache`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs).

For `IMemoryCache` cache there is no need to explicitly serialize the `T`, you can use generic `Get` and `Set` methods. Just to get you started:

```cs
public class CacheService 
{
    // ...

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return _cache.Get<T>(key);
    }

    public T Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        _cache.Set(key, value, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(20),
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is for production.  I want to store stores data on the application server memory using Dapper. Kindly assist. Also I saw that this trying to Implement In-memory https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-in-memory-caching

Comment: @Ayobamilaye Redis is not in-memory caching from .NET process point of view.

Comment: How do I store data on the application server memory using Dapper. Kindly assist

Comment: `IMemoryCache` has `Get` and `Set` methods - use those.

Comment: How do I transform the code I have above into that? Thanks